# Meaning of this perl command

Tags: shell, perl

I found this command `perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/'` and I'd be very grateful if someone familiar with perl could tell me in a nutshell what exactly all the syntax means, it would save a lot of time trying to look this all up by myself.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `-n` reads the input line by line.
- `[^.\/]` is a character class, it matches everything except for a dot and slash.
- `+` means the character should appear at least once.
- `\.` matches a dot.
- `$` matches the end of string.
- `(...)` creates a capture group.
- the whole `m/.../` thing is a regular expression match, it matches a dot followed by non-dots and non-slashes until the end of the string. The non-dot-non-slash part is remembered in `$1`.
- If there was a match, it's printed.

Comment: And the -e in -ne? Anyways, thanks a lot! You saved me hours of trying to look this all up : )

Comment: `-e` just indicates the code itself follows. Instead of a "thank you", you can upvote/accept the answer.